# Laravel eloquent query with filter "where ILIKE" does not match with any value with accent saved in my Postgre database (encoded in UTF8)

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Laravel 5.8 app. It works with a Postgres Database encoded with UTF8.

I have a query for my users table, so i made my query as:

```
$users = User::where('name', 'ILIKE', '%Jose%')->get()
```

It give me back the rows who match with "Jose" but let aside rows with "José". How i can do it (get all rows, who match with "Jose" and "José")?

Comment: Don't you mean `LIKE` in the second argument of the `where()`?

Comment: No, ILIKE means "Insensitive", im trying to ignore accent mark in the searching

Comment: Use unaccent module https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unaccent.html

Comment: Yeah, but how i can work with it using the eloquent interface (Laravel ORM) @KorayKüpe

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using whereRaw like this:

```
$users = User::whereRaw('lower(name) ILIKE ?',['%Jose%'])->get();
```